# Image Uploader in Dynamic Rows Ui Component not saved since Magento 2.3.3

Tags: magento2, validation, image-upload, dynamic-rows, magento2.3.3

I made a module using dynamic rows component with imageUploader field inside. I was able to upload my image on the Magento 2.3.2, but since the new release (2.3.3), I can't pass the `valideFileId()` method in the class `\Magento\Framework\File\Uploader`.

If I take a look at the `valideFileId()` method, here is what I see :

```
private function validateFileId(array $fileId): void
    {
        $isValid = false;
        if (isset($fileId['tmp_name'])) {
            $tmpName = trim($fileId['tmp_name']);

            if (preg_match('/\.\.(\\\|\/)/', $tmpName) !== 1) {
                $allowedFolders = [
                    sys_get_temp_dir(),
                    $this->directoryList->getPath(DirectoryList::MEDIA),
                    $this->directoryList->getPath(DirectoryList::VAR_DIR),
                    $this->directoryList->getPath(DirectoryList::TMP),
                    $this->directoryList->getPath(DirectoryList::UPLOAD),
                ];

                $disallowedFolders = [
                    $this->directoryList->getPath(DirectoryList::LOG),
                ];

                foreach ($allowedFolders as $allowedFolder) {
                    if (stripos($tmpName, $allowedFolder) === 0) {
                        $isValid = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                foreach ($disallowedFolders as $disallowedFolder) {
                    if (stripos($tmpName, $disallowedFolder) === 0) {
                        $isValid = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (!$isValid) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException(
                __('Invalid parameter given. A valid $fileId[tmp_name] is expected.')
            );
        }
    }
```

This private method is called from the `_setUploadFileId()` which is called in the constructor.

Here is this method on **Magento 2.3.2**:

```
 private function _setUploadFileId($fileId)
    {
        if (is_array($fileId)) {
            $this->_uploadType = self::MULTIPLE_STYLE;
            $this->_file = $fileId;
        } else {
            if (empty($_FILES)) {
                throw new \Exception('$_FILES array is empty');
            }
```

and now on **Magento 2.3.3**:

```
private function _setUploadFileId($fileId)
    {
       if (is_array($fileId)) {
            $this->validateFileId($fileId);
            $this->_uploadType = self::MULTIPLE_STYLE;
            $this->_file = $fileId;
        } else {
            if (empty($_FILES)) {
                throw new \DomainException('$_FILES array is empty');
            }
```

Here is the data that I send:

```
array(5) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(9) "image1.jpg"
  ["type"]=>
  string(10) "image/jpeg"
  ["tmp_name"]=>
  string(26) "/private/var/tmp/phpbPsgJz"
  ["error"]=>
  int(0)
  ["size"]=>
  int(72987)
}
```

Here is how I get my data:

```
$result = $this->imageUploader->saveFileToTmpDir($imageId);
```

`imageUploader` being the class `\Magento\Catalog\Model\ImageUploader`

My `tmp_name` is `"/private/var/tmp/phpbPsgJz"`

I run my project on Mac Os.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please refer the below link for your issue, https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/165706/uicomponent-dynamic-rows-image-upload-problem/302851#302851

Answer (score 1):

In some of Mac Os versions (or maybe in all, not sure) root **"/var"** folder is a symlink which points to **"/var/private"**.
Php "opens" this symlink for tmp file path in $_FILES archive, but sys_get_temp_dir() returns configured in php.ini value (or, if not configured default value whic is **"var/tmp"** )
So for validating sys_get_temp_dir() with real tmp file path just configure in your php.ini next values:

```
upload_tmp_dir = "/private/var/tmp/"
sys_temp_dir = "/private/var/tmp/"
```

Answer (score 0):

I found finally what was the issue. For some reason as I wrote, my `tmp_name` was `"/private/var/tmp/phpbPsgJz"` and the `$allowedFolders` are :

```
"/var/tmp/"
"/Users/me/www/magento2/pub/media"
"/Users/me/www/magento2/var"
"/Users/me/www/magento2/var/tmp"
"/Users/me/www/magento2/pub/media/upload"
```

I had to rename my tmp_name in order to remove the "private" but it's not a clean  solution... Feel free to share your thoughts